# Нужна помощь по извлечению текста

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, анализ-данных

Есть текст. Например, `"Джексон: текст. Норрисон: говорит текст. еще говорит. дальше говорит. Джексон: текст. Норрисон: говорит текст. "` Мне нужно вытащить все, что говорит  Норрисон.

Регулярка `"Норрисон:(.+?\.)"`, например, помогает только первое предложение взять, а нужно все что относится к персонажу.

Помогите плиз, может кто подскажет как правильно регулярное выражение составить.

Comment: код ваш где? может, вы как раз в своем коде и ищете только первое предложение, а остальные - не ищете.

Comment: да, в этом и беда я не могу додумать как правильно сделать:

Comment: text = ' Джексон: слова. Норрисон: говорит текст. еще говорит. дальше говорит. Джексон: слова. Норрисон: говорит текст'. мне нужно на выходе, чтобы я мог извлечь такие данные: "говорит текст. еще говорит. дальше говорит" и "говорит текст", то есть то что говорит именно Норрисон

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте воспользоваться позитивным просмотром вперед:

```
Норрисон:.*?(?=\.[ \t]*\S+:|\Z)
```

Захватываем весь текст до следующего говорящего (текст:) или конца строки `\Z`

Comment: класс. спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

В регулярке укажите что должна быть группа символов без двоеточий (`[^:]+`), заканчивающаяся на точку (`\.`). Вопрос после `+` не ставьте, иначе так и будет находить до первой точки (наименьшую группу).

Пример:

```py
import re

text = "Джексон: текст Джексона. Норрисон: текст Норрисона. еще говорит. дальше говорит. Джексон: текст. Норрисон: опять текст Норрисона. "

result = re.findall(r"Норрисон: ([^:]+\.)", text)
print(result)
```

Вывод:

```py
['текст Норрисона. еще говорит. дальше говорит.', 'опять текст Норрисона.']
```

Более общий вариант с извлечением имен:

```py
import re

text = "Джексон: текст Джексона. Норрисон: текст Норрисона. еще говорит. дальше говорит. Джексон: текст. Еще текст Джексона. Норрисон: опять текст Норрисона. "

result = re.findall(r"(\w+): ([^:]+\.)", text)
print(result)
```

Вывод:

```py
[('Джексон', 'текст Джексона.'), ('Норрисон', 'текст Норрисона. еще говорит. дальше говорит.'), ('Джексон', 'текст. Еще текст Джексона.'), ('Норрисон', 'опять текст Норрисона.')]
```